# How do I see the contents of Qt objects QByteArray during debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-studio-debugging, qbytearray

My program use some variables of type QByteArray to contain data (bytes). That bytes maybe are special characters like '\0', 1, ... So I cannot see all elements after special character when debugging. If I use std::vector, I can see all elements. I must use QByteArray but I cannot see all element of this variable when debugging. Help me, plz!
Thanks!

Example: QByteArray bytes(4, '\0');
Now, if debug, I just see "". But I want to see "'\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'" or something like like this.

I also have the same problem with QDateTime. But I resolved by this help: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32336-View-QDate-and-QDateTime-in-VisualStudio-debugger

This link may help but this not resolve my problem: http://qt-project.org/wiki/IDE-debug-helpers

Example:

```
QByteArray ba("Hello"); //debuging, see: ba = "Hello"     
ba.append('\0');     
ba.append("a message"); //we just see: ba = "Hello"
```

Comment: ba.replace( "\0", "\\0" ) if it's just about 0 bytes. ba.toHex() is generally useful for chars that cannot be printed.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: no, it maybe any character

Comment: @aviit What other characters are giving you difficulties?

Answer (score 3):

I contribute here a piece of code I had to write since I could not find any method doing something close to that: *display a QByteArray as a meaningful QString* in a way python would do it: *ascii is kept as this, special char are displayed as hexadecimal code*.

If someone knows a better way ! (here it's QT 4.6)

```
QString toDebug(const QByteArray & line) {

    QString s;
    uchar c;

    for ( int i=0 ; i < line.size() ; i++ ){
        c = line[i];
        if ( c >= 0x20 and c <= 126 ) {
            s.append(c);
        } else {
            s.append(QString("<%1>").arg(c, 2, 16, QChar('0')));
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Such as:

```
QByteArray a;
a.append("et");
a.append('\0');
a.append("voilà");
qDebug() << toDebug(QByteArray(a));
```

returns:

```
"et<00>voil<e0>"
```

Answer (score 1):

For debugging, you can convert QBytearray to QString and see the output.

For example:

```
QByteArray bArray;

QString str = "";

str.append(bArray);

QDebug() << str ; // this will display the content in your console/application output  window
```

hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: The result is same, because QString cannot view all character that after first unprintable character.
My mean is to debug in IDE (Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: I think i got it, its a problem with '\0' this, instead you try using '\\0'. because single slash is used as command, thus '\0' means Null character in linux.
Please give it a try. I faced this problem many time.